Buck-boost output drops when loaded
The LTC3566, a PMIC intended for battery and USB supplied applications, integrates a battery charger, a power path and a buck-boost converter. For my board, I copy-pasted the schematic found on the last page of the datasheet.

During my test, I supply VBAT_POS with 3.8 V, to simulate a battery. The dc-dc converter should deliver 1 A, 3.3 V, but if I connect to 3V3 a 5.6 Ω resistor (580 mA), the 3V3 drops to an average of 2.4 V with a 50 kHz, 880 mV ripple (see oscillogram below). In 20 seconds the IC gets hot, increasing of +40°C. A similar behavior happens with lighter loads, e.g. 20 Ω. On the other side, if I apply no load, 3V3 is 3.3 V stable.

Anyway, if I load Vout (the output of the USB/battey power path) with 500 mA, the voltage is stable, so I assume the problem is on the dc-dc converter side. I already tried the type I compensation suggested in the datasheet on first page, but I get similar results.
What could I investigate?
EDIT:
Hereafter the Altium layout, with power components selected in light grey. Resistors are 0402. Inside the board and on TOP layer there are two GND planes. C1 and C3 are on top side connected with many vias.


@winny The input is stable. The ripple is 50 KiloHz, but the frequency changes according to the load and/or compensation, down to 32 KiloHz.

@Isacco - Hi, Please edit the question and link to the source of the original version of the schematic (the datasheet?) since you explain that the diagram was effectively copied from there. TY

Oh, us, not ms. Sorry about that. What’s the ESR of the output capacitor? How’s the loop compensation?

@Isacco Have you considered just buying their evaluation board? It's not overly expensive. Test with that. It may help you quickly find problems. Are you using a solderless breadboard?

What is your PCB layout for this project?

What inductor are you using?

@winny the capacitors are generic and were were chosen by manufacturer. I think ESR is about 5mOhm, as usual for MLCC. Can ESR be much worse for MLCC? The loop compensation is type III and is copied from the datasheet, as well as all the power components.

@winny LPS4018-332MRC and LPS4018-222MRC, which were suggested by the datasheet and demo board.

It appears from the schematic that instead of tying to VUSB like you do with ILIM0/1, you're sending the 3V3 output of VOUT1 (pin 10) to the MODE input (pin 8), which would seem like an opportunity for inadvertent mode switching when there is a sag in the switching regulator. It's difficult to tell from the single layer PCB screenshot whether this is actually wired that way. Is this maybe just a typo in the schematic? Just wanting to double check obvious things first.

Good, then those can be ruled out.

The LTC3566 datasheet, in section "Buck-Boost Regulator Burst Mode Operation", states: "The maximum load current in Burst Mode operation is 50mA. [...] if the load current increases beyond this point while in Burst Mode operation the output will lose regulation".
Therefore the solution was to configure pin 8, "MODE", to avoid burst operation. The pin must be connected to ground or left floating, since it has an internal pull-down.
